# Is there a convenience constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, this, rvalue, constructor-overloading

Is it possible for an overloaded constructor to somehow call another constructor within the class, similar to the code below?

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::string str) : m_str(str) {}
    A(int i) { *this = std::move(A(std::to_string(i))); }

    std::string m_str;
};
```

The code above works, yet I am afraid that calling this in the constructor might lead to undefined behavior.

If it does could you please explain why and also suggest a better alternative?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "delegate constructors".

Comment: Why not `A(int i) : m_str(std::to_string(i)) {}`?

Comment: This is a minimal example. I want to overload a constructor that accepts 7 parameters, 4 of which have default values and I want to avoid explicitly setting the defaults in more than one place.

Comment: @Makaronodentro: But you've still got to give the defaults twice, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, with defaults:
A(std::string str1, str::string str2="abc") : m_str1(str1), m_str2(str2) {}
delegating:
A(int i) : A(std::move(std::to_string(i))) {}

Comment: `std::move(std::to_string(i))` That "move" is redundant. `std::to_string(i)` is already an rvalue. Recall that `std::move` doesn't actually perform a move

Answer (score 30, accepted):

C++11 introduced [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor):

```
class A
    {
    public:
    std::string m_str;
    A(std::string str) : m_str(str) {} // target constructor
    A(int i) : A(std::to_string(i)) {} // delegating constructor
    };
```

Comment: Might be worth it to `m_str(std::move(str))`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the target constructor is called before the delegating constructor, so in the body of the latter, you can assume the former was called.